# SharePoint 2010 Mysite already exists after fixing User Profile Service Application

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

We experienced an issue with the User Profile Service Application, and had to rebuild it (by deleting the Sync DB, and re-using the Profile and Social DB's.

The service is working (importing user profiles, etc, and allowing new users to create MySites), but existing users with MySites are unable to access their content.  The error that is presented is:  "Your personal site cannot be created because a site already exists with your username.  Contact your site administrator for more information."

The MySite site collections DO show up in Central Admin.
Deleting the MySites is not a viable option.

The diagnostic logs state that that there is a user name conflict.  Makes sense, the site already exists.  How do I get SharePoint to sync up with the user profile service?  Running a UPS sync hasn't fixed the issue.
I've looked at the PowerShell cmdlets for the service application, but don't see anything that would immediately help.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

I had created a User Policy over a year ago, specifically for the MySite application users, which restrict creating subsites.

The OOTB ALL Authenticated Users isn't resolving correctly, causing that piece to fail (servers need to be rebooted).

I removed that policy, and users are now able to access their MySites again.  I believe that part of that MySite.aspx page is checking if the site exists via a http get, and if it is not found, attempts to create the new site.  The policy was preventing the entry in the Sync DB (I had rebuilt the user profile service, re-using the Profile & Social DB's).